# Extjs - Best way to display data

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I using extjs and i want display my dynamic data like bellow
[image]

I use xtype: displayfield but i think it's not well and i can't use it to make like my picture

```
items: [

    {
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            style: 'border: 1px solid #CCCCCC', 
            fieldLabel: 'a',
            name: 'a',
            value: 'a'
        }, {
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            style: 'border: 1px solid #CCCCCC', 
            fieldLabel: 'b',
            name: 'b',
            value: 'b'
    }],
```

any idea? How to do that thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such a complex layout, and considering you apparently just need to display data, I'd go with a component with a [custom template](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-tpl). This way, you can leverage HTML & CSS for presentation.

Here's, for example, how to make a reusable panel:

```
Ext.define('My.BudgetPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel'

    ,tpl: '<table>'
        // notice template variables
        + '<tr><td>{definedProject}</td><td>{definedPM}</td></tr>'
        + '</table>'
});
```

You can pass it your data at creation:

```
var panel = Ext.create('My.BudgetPanel', {
    data: {
        definedProject: 'My Project'
        ,definedPM: 'Foo Bar'
    }
});
```

And you can update with new data later:

```
panel.update({definedProject: 'My Project 2', definedPM: 'Baz Bat'});
```

Comment: I try that but when i break line I must using + operator :(. example my below code will not working. 
' <table> // break line here
 <tr><td></td></tr> // break line here
  </table> // break line here
'

Comment: No HEREDOC in Javascript :-( Maybe this [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/805107/1387519) can help...